# Working with ProcessPoolExecutor.(Windows) Where do all the classes and functions go, that have nothing to do with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, process-pool

+++ I EDITED MY QUESTION, TO REFLECT WHAT I THINK IS THE CORRECT STRUCTURE NOW, so that not necessary things don't get loaded in the child workers.. with the help of @booboo +++ THX

Where do all my classes and functions go(that have nothing to do with multiprocessing), so they are not loaded into every single process,....inside main or inside other files?

Should all my multiprocessing functions go into a separate file, to avoid loading unnecessary classes and functions into the processes?
I think this is what seems most logical.

None of the written tutorials/videos talk about it.

```
import myMulti

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    from time import sleep, time
    import concurrent.futures
    import myClasses

    folder = 'G:\+++CODING+++\Thin-Plate-Spline-Motion-Model-Windows-main\\assets\\test28\\'

    # some classes
    # some classesresultlist=[]
    start_time = time()
    resultlist=[]
    def create_filepaths(folder):
        return sorted([os.path.join(folder, f) for f in os.scandir(folder)])


    def update_chunks_to_gui(future_object, local_last_chunk_index,processing_abort=False):
        if processing_abort:  # If user changes directory, thumbnail creating will be canceled.
            for image in future_object:
                image.cancel()
        else:
            for index, image in enumerate(future_object[local_last_chunk_index:]):
                if image.done():
                    resultlist.append((image.result()))  # resultlist is just for Demo....update GUI with image
                    local_last_chunk_index += 1
                else:
                    break
            return local_last_chunk_index


    def start_job(filepaths):
        print('...starting jobs')
        pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=12)
        return [pool.submit(myMulti.process_file, file) for file in filepaths]

    def main():
        filepaths = create_filepaths(folder)
        last_chunk_index = 0

        future = start_job(filepaths)

        while True:  # GUI and general logic Main Loop
            # do stuff
            # do stuff
            print('+')
            sleep(0.5)
            if not last_chunk_index == len(future):
                last_chunk_index = update_chunks_to_gui(future, last_chunk_index)  # processing_abort=True if jobs needs to be canceled, for example when user changes folder
            else:
                print("...all done in:", time()-start_time)
                quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I now have tried is....
this in a seperate file that I import into my main program:

What is the right approach, that I don't load unnecessary methods/modules/classes/functions in the processes?

myMultiprocessing:

```
import PIL.Image
import io
import base64


def convert_to_bytes(file_or_bytes, resize=None, fill_blanc_color=None):
    if isinstance(file_or_bytes, str):
        img = PIL.Image.open(file_or_bytes)
        if file_or_bytes.endswith(".jpg"):
            img.draft('RGB', resize if resize else None )
    else:
        try:
            img = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(file_or_bytes)))
        except Exception as e:
            dataBytesIO = io.BytesIO(file_or_bytes)
            img = PIL.Image.open(dataBytesIO)
    if resize:
        img = img.resize((int(img.size[0]*min(resize[0]/img.size[1], resize[0]/img.size[0])),
                          int(img.size[1]*min(resize[1]/img.size[1], resize[0]/img.size[0]))),
                         PIL.Image.HAMMING).convert("RGBA")
    if fill_blanc_color:
        r, g, b = fill_blanc_color
        newimg = PIL.Image.new("RGB", resize if resize else img.size, (r, g, b))
        newimg.paste(img, (int((100-img.width)/2), int((100-img.height)/2)), img)
        img=newimg
    with io.BytesIO() as data:
        img.save(data, format="PNG")
        #del newimg
        del img
        return data.getvalue()


def process_file(filepath):
    return convert_to_bytes(filepath, resize=(100, 100), fill_blanc_color=(90, 105, 121))
```

BTW here is a picture on what I am working on, this is my first python program.
But pretty fun to learn all the concepts needed as I go along.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't stated your platform as the guidelines for Python multiprocessing request. I will assume you are running under a platforms such as Windows that uses the *spawn* method to create new processes.

In that case every new process is initialized by starting off with essentially uninitialized memory into which a new Python interpreter is started, which re-reads the source program initializing memory be processing everything at global scope (import statements, function definitions, global variable declarations and any executable code at global scope) *unless* what is at global scope is contained within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block (the `if` statement will be executed but the test will fail).

So, to save some execution time, put whatever you do not require by the child processes within such a block. For instance:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    import myClasses
    import time

def process_file(filepath): #Multiprocessing
    return Processed file
 

def main():
    # myClasses in main()???
    # def some functions
    # def some functions  
   
    def create_filepaths(folder):
        return sorted([os.path.join(folder, f) for f in os.scandir(folder)])


    def update_chunks_to_GUI(future_object):
         # update chunks to GUI

    filepaths = create_filepaths(folder)
    last_chunk_index = 0

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as pool:
        future = [pool.submit(process_file, file) for file in filepaths]

        while True:              # GUI and general logic Main Loop
            # do stuff
            # do stuff
            update_chunks_to_GUI(future)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If, for example, `process_file` required function from the `time` module, you would *not* include `import time` in such a block:

```py
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    import myClasses

def process_file(filepath): #Multiprocessing
    return Processed file
 

def main():
    # myClasses in main()???
    # def some functions
    # def some functions  
   
    def create_filepaths(folder):
        return sorted([os.path.join(folder, f) for f in os.scandir(folder)])


    def update_chunks_to_GUI(future_object):
         # update chunks to GUI

    filepaths = create_filepaths(folder)
    last_chunk_index = 0

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as pool:
        future = [pool.submit(process_file, file) for file in filepaths]

        while True:              # GUI and general logic Main Loop
            # do stuff
            # do stuff
            update_chunks_to_GUI(future)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: wow that's exactly what I wanted to know. THANK YOU SO MUCH!! You explained perfectly how to use it in one file. I did not realize I can use `if __name__ == '__main__':` more than once...stupid me.
How about if I put the pool related stuff into a seperate file?
does it still matter how my main program is structured regarding `if __name__ == '__main__':` I guess it does. So would the correct approach in my mainprogram be: `import MyMultiprocessing ; if __name__ == '__main__': ; import everything else etc`
And import the modules that are needed for multi inside myMultiprocessinjg file?

Comment: You really made me soo happy, because everything works, but I want to fully understand things before I implement and use them. I asked this question now 3 times, 2 here(differently structured), one on codereview,...but was told my question is not for stack, and I should try codereview, where they closed my question, because they said it's a design review, which they don't do.
I know that it was probably my fault, by not phrasing it right, but it seems you understood me perfectly.

Comment: I guess it depends on what is in `MyMultiprocessing`. If it has an `import concurrent.futures` statement, which is something that child processes do not need to see, then it *should* be in the `if` block if you care about squeezing out every bit of CPU.  I don't think we should get too carried away with all of this. In practice I do not worry about this too much unless I thought importing a  module  would have unwanted side-effects or take a long time to load, like 'pandas`. (more ...)

Comment: Also, note that when you import module  `a`, regardless of what process is doing the importing, then `__name__` in that module will be `'a'`.

Comment: MyMultiprocessing is everything related to multiprocessing, like in my 2nd codeblock of the question. I updated my question to reflect the correct structure I think should look like. I know not to worry too much, since the examples are too small to matter, but if I would be 100% correct('import concurrent.futures statement, which is something that child processes do not need to see') I would need to put `import concurrent.futures` in my mainprogram after the `if __name__ == '__main__' `, AND of course put `def start_job` also in my mainprogram after  `if __name__ == '__main__'` of course??

Comment: because not sure how to "protect" `import concurrent.futures` inside myMulti without breaking it.

Comment: I believe you could even put `import `myMulti` within the `if` block. As it is currently, that import statement will be unnecessarily executed again when each child process is created because it will have been implicitly imported  anyway just because the worker function being invoked by the main process, `process_file`, is in that module. As long as `myMulti` has the imports that it needs and any additional definitions it needs from the main script file (the main process) are not declared within the `if` block, `process_file` will have all the definitions it needs. Try it and let me know.

Comment: But in the end it is not a big deal one way or another. If the import statement is re-executed nothing will be done since the module is already imported. On platforms like Linux that use the *fork* method to create new processes, it doesn't matter at all. The child process inherits from the main process the state of the main process at the time of its creation and that includes any imports the main process did. That is, memory is therefore not initialized by launching another interpreter and re-reading source.

Comment: Well it works, but I don't know how to check the memory footprint of the worker children. Anyway, I implemented it in my file-explorer, and it makes the thumbnails nearly faster than I can scroll down ..lol. Thumbnail-cache will be next function. Btw I added a picture of my project, which is my first program in python btw, and my biggest project in general. Had a bit C# experience before. It supports multiselection, keyboard support, like  "del" or "shift +del", has a .ini, custom foldericons, driveicons and growing better by the day. I can send you my progress so far if you are interested....